# npm install not correctly omitting devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

My `package.json` comprises the following:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@loopback/apiconnect": "^0.11.0",
    "@loopback/authentication": "^10.1.2",
    "@loopback/boot": "^6.0.0",
    "@loopback/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@loopback/repository": "^6.1.2",
    "@loopback/rest": "^13.0.0",
    "@loopback/security": "^0.10.2",
    "@loopback/service-proxy": "^6.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "ldapauth-fork": "^5.0.5",
    "loopback-connector-db2": "^2.2.3",
    "pino": "^8.15.0",
    "pino-http": "^8.4.0",
    "pino-syslog": "^3.0.0",
    "rate-limiter-flexible": "^2.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@loopback/build": "^10.0.0",
    "@loopback/eslint-config": "^14.0.0",
    "@loopback/testlab": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.47",
    "@types/pino-http": "^5.8.1",
    "eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
```

I've tried `npm install --omit dev`, `npm install --omit=dev`, and `npm install --production` but in all cases I've noticed that the `node_modules` folder still contains all of the development-only packages listed above.

However, when I run `npm ls --all --omit dev` the displayed dependency tree correctly omits development-only packages.

What's going on? This is making my deployment package to the test and production environments unnecessarily large.